# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" on dojo/request/iframe post

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe, dojo, image-upload

I have an image upload function that uploads form with image like this:

```
iframe(url, {
    form: dom.byId("myform"),
    handleAs: "json",
    timeout: 5000,
    method: "POST"
}).then(function () {
    console.log("Success");
}, function (Err) {
    console.log(Err);
});
```

On server side I get the image, but on client side I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined↵    at I [as handleResponse] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/request/iframe.js:9:114)↵    at r (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/dojo.js:206:81)". I have no returned value! I do not get what causing the error!
Please help!

Comment: Your links are broken. Where does this error occur in your code? Pointing them to `iframe.js` isn't very helpful...

Comment: I get value of Err = "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined↵ at I [as handleResponse] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/request/iframe.js:9:114)↵ at r (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/dojo.js:206:81) "! It's not my fault that the links are broken! It's the value of the error!

Comment: In the future, please post your relevant server code as well, especially since you tagged this post with asp.net-mvc-4. It took a lot longer to find the cause of your issue because I couldn't tell what you were returning as a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the **[Dojo Reference Guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/iframe.html#content-handling)**:

> **Important:** If your payload is something other than html or xml (e.g. text, **JSON**) the server response needs to enclose the content
>   in a `<textarea>` tag. This is because this is the only cross-browser
>   way for this provider to know when the content has been successfully
>   loaded. Therefore the server response should look something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <textarea>
      payload
    </textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

All you should need to do to fix this issue is to wrap your JSON response in a `<textarea>` tag. The reason for this is in `iframe.js`, starting at line 300:

```
if(handleAs === 'xml'){
    ...
}else{
    // 'json' and 'javascript' and 'text'
    response.text = doc.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value; // text
}
```

So here is where you get your error that reads, "Cannot read property 'value' of `undefined`." Dojo can't find a `<textarea>` element in your response, so `doc.getElementsByTagName('textarea')` returns an empty array. The 0th element of an empty array, `[]`, is `undefined`, and dereferencing it will throw this error.

Comment: handleResponse is invoked even before the response is received from the server(the response is wrapped in textarea) and hence the above error.

Please note this is intemittent and happens(if it does) with the first file upload only. Works fine after that...

Comment: @HiteshBajaj Yes, there is a bug in the Dojo iframe class. I discovered this a few days ago. It's because the iframe's onload handler sometimes fires early due to the loading of the default blank.html page.

You can bypass this by overriding or replacing the dojo_request_iframe_onload() method on the dojo/_base/window win.global object. Look for blank.html in the iframe.doc(iframe._frame).location.href and ignore the event if you see it, otherwise call the original dojo_request_iframe_onload() method.

Alternatively, you can try preloading the iframe by manually calling iframe.create().